# Could someone explain steps?

Tags: logarithms

I am learining about logarithm equations, and i can´t seem to understand how to solve such an equation, could someone help?

I must solve the equation/find $x$ for:

$$2^{2x} - 3\cdot2^x - 10=0$$

The final answer should be 
$x=\dfrac{\log5}{\log2}$

Comment: Where is the equation sign?

Comment: It´s an old textbook and it only says: 
Solve the equation(s) : **2^2x - 3 * 2^x - 10 = 0**

Comment: A few $( \ ,\ )$ would be useful to make your equation clear.

Comment: Please, edit. \$\$2^{2x}-2^x=10\$$ would look much nicer.

Comment: You have two equations that are not the same.  The second is factored, so you just set each factor to zero.  Neither gives the answer you seek.  Also 2^2x should be read as $2^2x=4x$, but I suspect you mean $2^{2x}$.  Please be careful with parentheses.

Comment: If you put $y = 2^x$ then your equation for y is $y^2-3y-10=0$. Solve for y then solve $y = 2^x$ for x (if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean $2^{2x} - 3\times2^x - 10 = 0$, then since this is a quadratic in  $2^x$ we can factorise as $(2^x+2)(2^x-5)=0$. Since $2^x>0$ $\forall x$, $2^x+2\neq0$, so we must have $2^x=5$. Taking logarithms and applying the power rule, $x\log2=\log5$, whence $x=\frac{\log5}{\log2}$ as required.

If you're having trouble seeing the factorisation, then try setting $y=2^x$ and solving the resulting quadratic for $y$, then using logarithms to obtain $x$.

Comment: Could you explain how you factorised it to be: $$(2^x+2)(2^x−5)$$?

Comment: One way to see that that I and others have mentioned is that if you let $y=2^x$, then $2^{2x}-3\times2^x-10=y^2-3y-10=0$, because $2^{2x} = 2^x\times2^x = (2^x)^2 = y^2$.

Then it's just a quadratic in $y$ - I assume you are familiar with its solution?